# Dividing a list in specific number of sublists

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming

I want to divide a list in "a specific number of" sublists.

That is, for example if I have  a list `List(34, 11, 23, 1, 9, 83, 5)` and the number of sublists expected is 3 then I want `List(List(34, 11), List(23, 1), List(9, 83, 5))`.

How do I go about doing this? I tried `grouped` but it doesn't seem to be doing what I want.

PS: This is not a homework question. Kindly give a direct solution instead of some vague suggestions.

EDIT:

A little change in the requirements...

Given a list `List(34, 11, 23, 1, 9, 83, 5)` and number of sublists = 3, I want the output to be `List(List(34), List(11), List(23, 1, 9, 83, 5))`. (i.e. 1 element per list except for the last list which holds all the remaining elements.)

Answer (score 4):

In response to your changed requirements,

```
def splitN[A](list: List[A], n: Int): List[List[A]] =
  if(n == 1) List(list) else List(list.head) :: splitN(list.tail, n - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's a tough call, because you don't know how many elements to put into each list before you know the size of the list. If you *do* know the size of the list, you can use grouped: `list.grouped((list.size + 2) / 3).toList`. It will not divide the elements like you did, though.

Question: does the order matter? If the order of the elements need not be preserved, then there are better ways of accomplishing this.

Answer (score 2):

If you can tolerate a call to get the length of the list, then

```
l.grouped( (l.length+2)/3 ).toList
```

will produce something akin to what you want (if `val l = List(34, 11, 23, 1, 9, 83, 5)` then you'll get `List(List(34, 11, 23), List(1, 9, 83), List(5))` back.  But if you want approximately equal distribution across your lists, then you'll have to create your own method to do it--there isn't a library function that partitions a list equally into `n` pieces.

Something like this would work, if you want to keep the pieces in order:

```
def chopList[T](
  l: List[T], pieces: Int,
  len: Int = -1, done: Int = 0, waiting: List[List[T]]=Nil
): List[List[T]] = {
  if (l isEmpty) waiting.reverse
  else {
    val n = (if (len<0) l.length else len)
    val ls = l.splitAt( (n.toLong*(done+1)/pieces - n.toLong*done/pieces).toInt )
    chopList(ls._2,pieces,n,done+1,ls._1 :: waiting)
  }
}
```

and this happens to return exactly what you want: `List(List(34, 11), List(23, 1), List(9, 83, 5))`.

If you don't want to ask for the length of the list, then you can write a method that creates a bunch of buckets and drops a new item in each in turn.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know it it answer to your problem, but here a try (what do you expect when count is outside of range) ?

```
def group[T](list:List[T], count:Int):List[List[T]] = {
  if (count <= 0 || count >= list.length)
    List(list)
  else {
    val numElm = list.length / count
    def loop(list:List[T], i:Int):List[List[T]] = {
      i match {
        case 0 => List(list) 
        case 1 => List(list)
        case _ =>  {
          val l = list.splitAt(numElm)
          l._1 :: loop(l._2, i-1)
        }
      }
    }
    loop(list, count)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is `grouped` new in 2.8? A selfmade solution for 2.7.7 could look like this:

```
def splitTo (li: List [Int], count: Int) : List [List [Int]] = {
    val size = li.length / count

    if (count > 1) li.take (size) :: splitTo (li.drop (size), count-1) else 
        li :: Nil
}
```

Parametrizing to List [T] is left as an excecise to the reader.

Comment: Yes, `grouped` is new in the Scala 2.8 collections library.